# Why does the JFrame object seem to stay alive, even though there aren't references to it?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

If I remember correctly, in Java one can write

```
new JFrame();
```

without saving the `JFrame` reference in any variable. This program will display a GUI window on screen and leave it open, until the program is closed. (Please correct me if this premise is false).

Theoretically, we could think that since the `JFrame` is now unreachable from user code, the GC should at some point free the object. And as a result, the associated OS resources (the GUI window, etc.) will be freed as well.

However, if my understanding is correct - that program is a valid and working Java program (albeit a pretty useless one), and it will not crash or behave in strange ways at any point (again correct me if this premise is wrong).

It seems that the GC will not collect the `JFrame` object even though there aren't any references to it, or at least it will not cause the associated OS resources to be freed.

I would like to understand: How is this possible?

1. Does the constructor of `JFrame` save `this` anywhere in order to not be collected? In the [source code for `JFrame`'s superclass java.awt.Frame](http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/Frame-source.html) (method `noteFrame`) the frame seems to be saved in a weak references queue. But since these are weak references, that doesn't seem to explain things
2. Is it in fact the case that the GC *does* eventually free the `JFrame` - however, the finalizer method of `JFrame` *doesn't* free the associated OS resources, thus the GUI window stays open?
3. Any other explanation?

Please note that this is a follow up question to a more [theoretical question I posted on SE.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/408251/how-do-vms-and-gcs-treat-objects-which-wrap-yet-active-resources-but-that-are-u). This question is different because it relates specifically to the Java implementation details.

Comment: The existence of [Window.getWindows()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows%28%29) and [Frame.getFrames()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames%28%29) proves that something in Java SE (like a static field) is keeping track of all of the Windows.  If you want a window garbage collected, [dispose](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#dispose%28%29) of it.

Comment: @VGR The implementation of java.awt.Frame.getFrames() (http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/awt/Frame-source.html) suggests that it's based on the weak references collection it keeps. So that shouldn't keep the JFrame from being GC'd, should it?

Comment: Don’t rely on source code to inform you of how things work.  There are other classes in the toolkit which are non-public and/or are in non-public packages which are involved.

Comment: since the created frame is visible, then it is referenced from the graphics subsystem, otherwise the subsystem could not draw it. And since it is referenced, it will not be garbage collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `JFrame` that is only created via `new JFrame()` without any additional actions will not get opened on the screen and not prevented from garbage collection. Only a frame connected to a display device will be referenced from the AWT implementation and can’t get garbage collected before it has been explicitly disconnected.

Which can be verified with the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    check(new JFrame(), "just creating a JFrame", x -> {});
    check(new JFrame(), "creating and connecting a JFrame", JFrame::pack);
    check(Frame.getFrames()[0], "calling dispose()", Frame::dispose);
}
private static <T> void check(T obj, String description, Consumer<T> action) {
    System.out.println(description);
    action.accept(obj);
    WeakReference<T> r = new WeakReference<>(obj);
    obj = null;
    System.gc();
    if(r.get() == null) System.out.println("collected immediately");
    else {
        System.runFinalization();
        System.gc();
        if(r.get() == null) System.out.println("collected after finalization");
        else System.out.println("still alive");
    }
}
```

which will print

```
just creating a JFrame
collected immediately
creating and connecting a JFrame
still alive
calling dispose()
collected after finalization
```

in typical implementations.

It’s worth noting that a frame that was never connected to a display device gets collected immediately like an ordinary object, whereas a frame which was connected and later-on disconnected via a `dispose()` call requires a cleanup action, which takes place after the first garbage collector run.

Further, the example uses `pack()` rather than `setVisible(true)`, to demonstrate that a frame can get connected to a display device without being visible. This makes the difference between [`isDisplayable()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isDisplayable--) which reflects whether the component is connected to a screen device and [`isVisible()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isVisible--) which tells whether the *visible* property has been set to `true`. Finally, a component does only report [`isShowing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#isShowing--) as `true` when it is visible and displayable and all of its parents are showing.

Comment: Are the "display devices" you are referring to Java classes (either native or regular) behind the scenes? And if so, does connecting to them prevent being collected by the GC simply by virtue of the existence of a reference to the frame?

Comment: It’s a concept, which can be implemented in different ways. In the case of the widespread OpenJDK, it’s a combination. There are Java classes behind the scenes, e.g. os specific implementations of `java.awt.peer.FramePeer`, but the `JFrame` will also be locked globally via JNI by the native code (at least, I observed this on Windows), further, there’s also a dedicated thread which handles native events behind the scenes, so this thread can have references even when the ordinary application threads have no visible references.